# Flutter - Trying to generate a service contract PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart, docx

I'm trying to generate a PDF document with an logo, costumer and service partner data via code. What is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flutter dev. You can use the pdf package. translates photo and text into pdf.
https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

Comment: have you tried?. if yes, please answer with some code